# selenium xpath is clicking on the wrong text

Tags: selenium, xpath

I am new to selenium.

I am using Facebook page and trying to enter "john" in the "mobile number or email" field  which is under Signup category

When I run the application the text "john" is entered in "Email or phone" field . which is under existing user category.

Below is the **xpath** which i am using. I know i can use other locators but want to try xpath locator.

```
WebElement mobile = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='reg_form_box']/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]"));

    mobile .sendKeys("john");
```

Comment: are you navigating to signup page ?

Comment: The input element is not there in your xpath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to handle `<div>` element while target should be `<input>`. Try following to select exact element:

```
WebElement mobile = driver.findElement(By.xpath('//input[@placeholder="Email or Phone Number"]'));
mobile .sendKeys("john");
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hi, Shakeer Mirza try with following code**

**xpath("html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/form/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/input"))**

Sample Script:

public class Facebook 
{
    static WebDriver driver;

```
@Test
public static void test() throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);        
    driver.manage().window().maximize();  

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/form/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/input")).sendKeys("admin");}}
```

Comment: 2 type of xpath 1. absolute xpath and 2. relative xpath

Answer (score 0):

Thank You all guys this is working correctly when i added the input in the end

WebElement mobile = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='reg_form_box']/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/input"));

```
    mobile .sendKeys("john");
```

now my question is when i did not added "input" in the end the application was entering the text on wrong field instead of throwing some error.